# jquery.each multidimensional array

Tags: jquery

```
var array1 = {};

array1['one'] = new Array();
array1['one']['data'] = 'some text';
array1['one']['two'] = new Array();
array1['one']['two']['three'] = new Array();
array1['one']['two']['three']['data'] = 'some other text';

$.each(array1, function(key1, value1){
    $.each(value1['two']['three'], function(key1, value1){
        document.write('test');
    }
});
```

everything works, except it doesnt get to the document.write.
Anyone an idea why?

Comment: Those are **not** Arrays you are using there, but normal Objects. Do no use `new Array()` but `new Object()` (or just `{}` for an "empty" object).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that the Array() replacement is key here with the missing ')'

```
var array1 = {};

array1['one'] = new Object();
array1['one']['data'] = 'some text';
array1['one']['two'] = new Object();
array1['one']['two']['three'] = new Object();
array1['one']['two']['three']['data'] = 'some other text';

$.each(array1, function(key1, value1) {
    $.each(value1['two']['three'], function(key1, value1) {
        document.write('test');
    });
});
```

and Another way to write the same thing:(small tweek on the write to reference your object)

```
var array1 = {};

array1.one = new Object();
array1.one.data = 'some text';
array1.one.two = new Object();
array1.one.two.three = new Object();
array1.one.two.three.data = 'some other text';


$.each(array1, function(key1, value1) {
    $.each(value1['two']['three'], function(key1, value1) {
        document.write('test' + array1.one.data);
    });
});
```

And finally, with the deprecated new Object() replacement:

```
var array1 = {};

array1['one'] = {}
array1['one']['data'] = 'some text';
array1['one']['two'] = {};
array1['one']['two']['three'] = {};
array1['one']['two']['three']['data'] = 'some other text';

$.each(array1, function(key1, value1) {
    $.each(value1['two']['three'], function(key1, value1) {
        document.write('test');
    });
});
```

EDIT: some fun with your array, and why you MIGHT have the strings in the object declaration as you have it:

```
var array1 = {}; 
var fun="four"; 
array1.one = {}; 
array1.one.data = 'some text'; 
array1.one.two = {}; 
array1.one.two.three = {}; 
array1.one.two.three.data = 'some other text'; 
array1.one.two[fun] = {};
array1.one.two[fun].data=' howdy';

$.each(array1, function(key1, value1) { 
    $.each(value1.two.three, function(key1, value1) { 
        document.write('test'+array1.one.two[fun].data+ ":"+key1+":"+value1); 
    }); 
});
```

the output the the last is: "test howdy:data:some other text"

Comment: Well, it's not REALLY an array, but fun anyway :) with your array1 object!

Comment: I resist posting more "fun" ways to declare this object set :)

Answer (score 1):

The document.write isn't working as you've a syntax error, so the code flow never gets to it - you need another bracket at the end of your `each`, i.e.

```
$.each(array1, function(key1, value1){
    $.each(value1['two']['three'], function(key1, value1){
        document.write('test');
    })
});
```

If you're going to be doing any non-trivial work with javascript, I'd highly recommend that you use Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) installed - it's console highlights these kind of errors which would otherwise fail without you realising, leading you to believe everything was working ok.

Comment: Yes on the platform, or another browser, but at least capture the error details Webpage error details as I did by clicking the error notation in an IE window by double clicking it in the status bar:

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)
Timestamp: Tue, 24 Aug 2010 15:28:09 UTC

Message: Expected ')'

Comment: that still does not hit the document.write as you see here: jsfiddle.net/yPYWd

Answer (score 1):

You miss `)` in the second `each`.

Comment: that still does not hit the document.write as you see here: http://jsfiddle.net/yPYWd/